# How to use an associative array in post__in with WP_Query?

Tags: php, wp-query, user-meta

I have stored user favorite posts in the `user_meta` table of WordPress. The data is stored in a format, for example `a:1:{s:8:"post-134";s:3:"134";s:8:"post-136";s:3:"136";}`.

How can I get this in the form of an array like `array( 134, 136 )` so that I can use it in the query below.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$query = new WP_Query( array( 
    'paged' => $paged, 
    'post_type' => 'post', 
    'post__in' => I WANT AN ARRAY HERE 
) );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) : 
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'content', 'fav' )
    endwhile;
    wp_pagenavi();
    wp_reset_postdata(); else :
        ?><div class="alert alert-warning">You have not faved any post.</div><?php
endif;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at PHP's [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) function. Alternatively, you could [typecast](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting).

Note that if the array is in serialized form as you have put it above, you will have to unserialize it first, in either case.

```
$numerical_array = array_values(
    unserialize(
        'a:1:{s:8:"post-134";s:3:"134";s:8:"post-136";s:3:"136";}'
    )
);
```

or

```
$numerical_array = (array) unserialize(
        'a:1:{s:8:"post-134";s:3:"134";s:8:"post-136";s:3:"136";}'
);
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I did not understand. I did it like this. `$favpsts = get_user_option( "_fav_posts", $current_user->ID  ); $fp_array = (array) unserialize($favpsts);` but it is not working.

Comment: For one, typecasting might have been a bad idea, since the result will probably remain associative. For another, the sample you posted is a broken serialization, since an array with two elements should start with `a:2` in serialized form - that however is out of scope of this question. Anyhow, use `array_values()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data from user meta with the below code

```
$pastids = get_user_meta($user_id, $key);
```

**$pastids** will be an array automatically. Now we can change its structure in any format.

if we pass an array to add_user_meta()
it will save it in serialized format and when we get it using **get_user_meta()**
it return save data in array format.